# Background of mini page

Tags: color, minipage

In a ‘mini page’ environment, is there a way to have a back ground and then writing on top? Rather than just writing and a translucent background.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Sure, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{blue!20}{\begin{minipage}{4cm}
xyz
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}`

Comment: Let me mention that there are much more advanced options such as `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document} 

\blindtext

\noindent
\fcolorbox{Brown}{Aqua}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule} 
\color{Brown}\blindtext 
\end{minipage}} 

or

\noindent
\colorbox{Khaki}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep} 
\blindtext 
\end{minipage}} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using either `tikz` or `framed` package, you can achieve it. Example given below:

```
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{shaded}
....
\end{shaded}
```

`tcolorbox` also having many features....